# Solving $\arccos(11/14)+\arcsin(-1/7)=x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Solve $\arccos(11/14)+\arcsin(-1/7).$

I'm using $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)+\sin(a)\sin(b).$

Attempt: [sheet1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bt1c25afgpia5jq/2013-09-24%2018.50.43.jpg) and [sheet2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uflor9tcn0xfhmh/2013-09-24%2018.50.48.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$
\begin{align}
&\sin\left(\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{11}{14}\right)-\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)\\
&=\sin\left(\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{11}{14}\right)\right)\cos\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)
-\cos\left(\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{11}{14}\right)\right)\sin\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{5\sqrt3}{14}\frac{4\sqrt3}{7}-\frac{11}{14}\frac17\\
&=\frac{49}{98}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Another Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
&\cos\left(\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{11}{14}\right)-\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)\\
&=\cos\left(\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{11}{14}\right)\right)\cos\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)
+\sin\left(\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{11}{14}\right)\right)\sin\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{11}{14}\frac{4\sqrt3}{7}+\frac{5\sqrt3}{14}\frac17\\
&=\frac{49\sqrt3}{98}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: You are doing the whole computation, except noting that $49/98=1/2$? :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I was thinking of leaving out the last line. Perhaps I should have. Of course, I didn't solve for $x$ :-)

Comment: You solved it for me, thanks. Where do I go wrong in my calculation?

Comment: The problem is that I get

sin(acos(11/14)) * cos(acos(11/14)) =
5(√3)/14 * 11/14

and
cos(asin(-1/7)) * sin(asin(-1/7) = 
4(√3)/7 * (-1/7).

See also [photo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y5jwvpuafyg1v7o/2013-09-24%2020.24.01.jpg)

Comment: @jacob: That should work, too. See the addition to my answer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I don't feel too guilty. jacob has tried, and I think he is almost there.